# C# - Unity3d save some variables in game?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, save

I would make sure when I close The Game , he saved automatically some variables ( scores ), and show them once started ?

To do this i need to use these to save an float?

```
void Awake
void Load
```

or i need these?

```
public void Load
public void Save
```

can you show me some example code line that works? thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A good option for that is to use the `OnEnable` and `OnDisable` [event functions](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html).

```
using UnityEngine;

public class GameSaver : MonoBehaviour
{
    int _score;

    void OnEnable()
    {
         _score = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Player Score");
    }

    void OnDisable()
    {
         PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Player Score", score);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        // change the _score during the game execution.
    }
}
```

Make sure that the object you attach the script to exists throughout the whole game. You also could call those functions manually from your code when you need it.

Of course, you could create your own methods called `Load` and `Save` or `Serialize` and `Deserialize` and then call them from `OnEnable` and `OnDisable`, like that:

```
void OnEnable()
{
    Load();
}

void Load()
{
    _score = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Player Score");
}
```

This will look better from the prorgammers point of view, but the program will work pretty much the same way.

You may also prefer to use the methods like `Awake` and `OnApplicationQuit`, but you still would need your game object to be alive from start to end, so this does not make much sense.

If you need to save more than just a few variables, you might want to take a look at the so called [Unity Serializer](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/3675).

Comment: thanks, but it only work in unity, when i try in android device it not save

Comment: @Amarildo Try adding `PlayerPrefs.Save()` just after you call `PlayerPrefs.SetInt()`. `PlayerPrefs` might work a bit different on different platforms.

Comment: Well, this code _should_ work. You now have a more specific problem with the particular OS (or even device). You need to debug/trace/log it and find out what exactly happens. The problems I could imagine so far: (1) `OnDisable` is not called for some reason on Android (if this is the problem, save values from another place in your code), (2) you have written some logic wrong and always save zero value (just fix it, if this is the case), (3) Android might not allow whitespaces in the player prefs key names (fix it, if you have any).

Comment: I tried everything doesn't work anyway. If you know any other way to rescue?

Comment: Well, I have no more ideas. This issue requires careful debugging and rechecking all the code and all the settings you have. Maybe you would need to create some simple separate projects to test different approaches. Maybe this is just a single device that is causing the problem. Maybe this is the app signing issue. Maybe something else. I just never encoutered such a problem so I can't be of much help here.